# What is the term for a rapid succession of chords in alternating hands?

Tags: piano, terminology

In piano music there's the technique called *blind octaves* where you create a rumbling melody over three octaves by playing the melody itself with the thumbs of your left and right hands alternatively, each octaved with the fourth or fifth fingers.
[image: blind octaves in Cziffra's Flight of the Bumblebee]
[image: blind octaves in Carnaval des Animaux]
I am looking for the word to describe the equivalent, but with whole chords. That can either stay with the same chord throughout the passage:
[image: alternating chords in Totentanz]
Or it can form a quasi-melody:
[image: more alternating chords in Totentanz]
Sometimes one hand plays octaves and the other chords:
[image: alternating chords in Shostakovich Piano Concerto 2]
Finally, Alkan's Concerto for Solo Piano does this for two and a half minutes! In [this video](https://youtu.be/W3XKeqy8xd4?t=1430), from 23:50 to 26:20. [This analysis](https://fdocuments.in/document/alkans-concerto-for-solo-piano-1st-movement-analysis.html) calls it  "alternate hands" or "alternate chords", but purely descriptively.

What is the general term for this technique, if there is one?

Comment: Upvoted. Interesting question and good examples, IMO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it just rhythmically articulating a chord *tremolo* or *shake* seems appropriate terms.

But when the tones move it seems there is a question of if there is a hand position change - in which case tremolo/shake simply isn't the technique - or if there is bona fide harmonic/melodic movement - in which case the passage isn't a mere ornament.

*Bravura* seem appropriate, but a bit generic.

From Mason's *Touch and Technic*...

[image]

[image]

For the chord based passages with some movement I suppose you can adapt Mason's wording and call it *interlocking chords*. Interlocking being understood to mean the distribution of the rhythm evenly between the two hands.

Looking around at some other method books, I found this convenient summary...

[image]

- Cisler, Technique for the Advancing Pianist: An Essential Collection of Progressive Exercises and Etudes

That provides *alternating hands* and *linked trills* as additional terms.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm not sure there's a better answer than the method works in this regards :)

Answer (score 1):

*Tremolo* comes to mind. Rapid repetition of certain sounds.

Not to be  confused with tremolo on electric guitar - which is a misnomer for 'vibrato'. Mr. Fender swapped the two round, and had the other on his amps, so also a misnomer!

Comment: But does any tremolo involve chords that don't repeat (a la the second last example and arguably the last example in the question)?

Comment: @Dekkadeci - Hmm, maybe - not... could be 'alternate hand playing.'